# IdentityServer IsActiveAsync method not being called on the profile service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, identityserver3, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer v4 to handle authorisation for my ASP.NET application, using Resource Owner flow.

I've implemented the `IdentityServer4.Core.Services.IProfileService` interface which has two methods, `GetProfileDataAsync` and `IsActiveAsync`.

When making a request to the token endpoint, the `GetProfileDataAsync` gets called as expected. We use this method to issue our claims.

However the `IsActiveAsync` method does not get called. I'd like to implement this method to determine whether the user is active in our database. At what point is this method supposed to get called?

The comment in the IdentityServer source (see below) suggests it should get called during token issuance, but the method isn't called when requesting a token. I suspect I'm missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    // Summary:
    // This method gets called whenever identity server needs to determine
    // if the user is valid or active (e.g. if the user's account has been
    // deactivated since they logged in). (e.g. during token issuance or 
    // validation).

    Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now `IsActiveAsync` does not get called for resource owner password requests. I guess the assumption was that you wouldn't successfully authenticate a user if the user is inactive.

These details are not yet decided on - if you have a strong opinion on how this should work - please open an issue on github. We will lock down the API in late August.